# Sending HTML Mails from Amazon SES using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, email, sdk

I am working on a service that sends emails from AWS SES service. I have been able to send plain text mails but I require to send rich HTML mails in one of the case. This is the code that I use:

```
header("MIME-Version: 1.0; Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php');

// Instantiate the Amazon class
$ses = new AmazonSES();


$source = 'abc@www..com';

$dest = array('ToAddresses'=>array($to));

$message = CFComplexType::map(array('Subject.Data'=>$subject, 'Body.Html.Data'=>$message_mail));

$rSendEmail = $ses->send_email($source, $dest, $message);
```

`message_mail` is some HTML text put inside tables.
I have tried both send_email and send_raw_email but both of them did not work. Do I need to do something extra or different?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's old question but still writing an answer. And hoping it will help someone in future.

```
$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
$m->addTo('receiver email address');
$m->setFrom('send email address');
$m->setSubject('testing!');

$body= '<b>Hello world</b>';
$plainTextBody = '';

$m->setMessageFromString($plainTextBody,$body);    
print_r($ses->sendEmail($m));
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me (without using the sdk or smtp):

```
require_once('ses.php');

$ses = new SimpleEmailService('accessKey', 'secretKey');

$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
$m->addTo('addressee@example.com');
$m->setFrom('Name <yourmail@example.com>');
$m->setSubject('You have got Email!');
$m->setMessageFromString('Your message');
$ses->sendEmail($m);
```

You can get ses.php from http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/

Comment: Do you happen to know if `print_r($ses->sendEmail($m));` would return bounce and abuse notifications in amazon's JSON format? Or is that not implemented in ses.php? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notification-examples.html

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the SES SDK and it was not easy to work with at all. I ended up using PHPMailer to connect to SES through SMTP. First, setup SMTP access from within Amazon SES and then add these lines to PHPMailer to have it connect to SES via TLS:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(true);
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host= "tls://email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "";  // SMTP username (Amazon Access Key)
$mail->Password = "";  // SMTP Password (Amazon Secret Key)

// ... the rest of PHPMailer code here ...
```

PHPMailer is very good at rich email (with text fallback), embedded images, and attachments.

Comment: Where do you paste your Access key and Secret key?

Comment: Your access key and secret are just the SMTP username and password fields! I updated the answer :)

Comment: thanks! by the way, which one do you think it is faster: SMTP or Amazon API?

Comment: I am not sure, but SMTP is pretty slow. Ours can only send about 2 emails per second, per thread. If you have the time to setup the Amazon API it's worth a shot.